# javascript replace --- to -

Tags: javascript, replace

How do I replace a string that contains --- to - ?

For example :

Vision & Mission

I've managed to replace space and other special characters to - and lower case the text, so the string becomes :

vision---mission

now i need another replace to replace --- to -

Of course, that should be flexible. So for example when user inputs Vision& Mission (typo intended) the replacing will generate vision--mission (two dashes), so in that case I will need to replace -- to -

so basically I need a replace technique to replace an undetermined number of dashes to only 1 dash.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, are you trying to replace a single em-dash character (`—`), or three dash characters (`---`)? Your question and its title disagree.

Comment: three dash characters. must have been the auto formatting in title text. i inputted three dash characters in the title.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it: in the edit window, they are again three dashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `replace` with a regexp telling to replace all sequences of dashes by a single dash.

```
"my--string".replace(/-+/g, "-"); // => "my-string"
```

Note that you could do that from the beginning, when you replace all the special characters and spaces by a dash. For example, the regexp literal `/[^a-z0-9]+/ig` finds all sequences of non alphanumeric characters.

```
"Smith & Wesson".replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/ig, "-"); // => "Smith-Wesson"
```

Then you just need to `.toLowerCase()` your string...

Comment: thanks! that's what i need. by the way what does /ig mean? g i assume is global right? so what is i?

Comment: The 'i' flag means case insensitive. If you didn't put it, you would need to write /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/ig (with explicit capital letters). 'g' flag is for global indeed.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing éxčëpť `a-zA-Z0-9` cóůld be an alphanumeric character? Poor Kurt Gödel - he'll become Kurt-G-del. Not all alphabetic characters are encoded by ASCII. +0 in total ;)

Comment: If the aim is to generate an ID without any accentuated character, you may use the code from this question before removing the special characters : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your whole function:

```
yourString.toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/g, '-')
```